# Why does Rails 4.2.6 uniqueness: true, case_sensitive: true fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple test to execute. Below is the following code:

```
  it 'should validate that email is lowercase' do
    account = build(:account, email: 'IRONMAN@gmail.com')
    lowercase_account = build(:account, email: 'warmachine@gmail.com')
    account.wont_be :valid?
    lowercase_account.must_be :valid?
  end
```

According to my test, `IRONMAN@gmail.com` should fail and `warmachine@gmail.com` should pass. However when I run the test, both emails pass.

Here is my validation code for my `Account` model.

```
validates :email, presence: :true, length: { in: 3..100 }, uniqueness: true,
                  confirmation: true, email_format: true, allow_blank: false
validates :email_confirmation, email_format: true, presence: true, allow_blank: false, on: :create
```

What could be the error here? I've referenced this link on SO as a starting point [Rails 4 validation case insensitivity test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055699/rails-4-validating-email-uniqueness-without-case-sensitive). It had some good information but I am using Postgresql and not MySQL to perform the account insertion. To my knowledge, Postgresql does not do a case insensitive search so I should be good. Has anyone experienced this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case sensitive doesn't mean everything must be lowercase to be valid, it means that you CAN have two emails like `hello@example.com` and `HELLO@example.com`.

If case sensitivity is set to false, you CANNOT have `hello@example.com` and `HELLO@example.com`